# Copy Cell to Specific Range with Math

Tags: excel, vba

In the example in the image, I have fields B2-B11 filled. I created a formula for C4, and I want to paste it from C4 to C9. But I need the range to change depending on what the last B cell filled is. So if it was B2-B14, it should paste from C4 to C12. I hope this makes sense. Any help is appreciated, let me know if I can clarify anything! I'm struggling to figure out how to make this dynamic in vba.

See the image for an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, y As Long, StartRow As Long, FinishRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        FinishRow = Lastrow - 2
        StartRow = 0

        For y = 1 To Lastrow

            If .Range("B" & y).Value <> "" Then
                StartRow = y + 2
                Exit For
            End If

        Next y

        'Start from line 4 and finish in line Lastrow-2
        For i = StartRow To FinishRow
            .Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```